# Angular 2 ngClass should switch onFocus

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class, onfocus

Changing a class with ngClass for Angular 2 works when using a check box, but it doesn't work when clicking into a input text box with the same class.

My guess is that the onFocus syntax is not correct.

see this plunker and look at the app.component.ts
https://plnkr.co/edit/0DeMvJQfY04Da2n4cGBm?p=preview
or see below for just the relevant code

Works: 2nd check box turns it to red.
Doesn't work: putting cursor in box should also make it red.

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'wrapper': true, 'wrapper-active': yyy }">

     <div id="log" class="login" >
       <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="xxx">
       <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="yyy">
      <form>
      <input  onfocus="focusFunction()" type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" />
      </form>
      </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrapper-active {
  background-color: red;

}
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
 
}
```

Comment: There's no **onfocus** event in Angular 2. You must use (focus)="focusFunction()"

Comment: @fals 
can I skip the function and just do something like
(focus)=" yyy = true"

Comment: just tried my suggestions.  yes that works.  thanks @Fals

Comment: Also onBlur could be used.